# Make a cell with ComboBox readonly on certain conditions WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, readonly, datagridtemplatecolumn

**What I have:**

I have a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ComboBox`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValuesCellTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValuesCellEditingTemplate">
      <ComboBox
            Name="ValuesComboBox"
            DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="DisplayText" />
</DataTemplate>
```

I am autogenerating the columns, so the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event looks like this:

```
if (e.PropertyName == "First")
{
    var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        Header = e.PropertyName,
        CellTemplate = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValuesCellTemplate") as DataTemplate,
        CellEditingTemplate = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValuesCellEditingTemplate") as DataTemplate
    };

    e.Column = templateColumn;
}
```

When `Values` (which is an `ObservableCollection`) is `null` I want the cell to be readonly, so it won't be able to enter CellEditing mode.

There are 2 options for the contents of this column:

- a simple integer - `SelectedValue`
- `ObservableCollection<int>` - `Values`

When `Values` has values inside, when double-clicking the cell (or the `TextBlock`)(so to say - entering CellEditing mode), a `ComboBox` should appear, otherwise not. That's basically it.

**What I have tried:**

I tried doing it this way:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValuesCellTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=OneWay}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ValuesCellEditingTemplate">
      <ComboBox
            Name="ValuesComboBox"
            DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"
            IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="DisplayText" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But when I double-click on it, the `TextBox` turns into an empty readonly `ComboBox` (enters CellEditing mode). I just want for it to take no action (be readonly)(ONLY when `Values` is `null`).

What is the proper way to do that?

For the record, I am using MVVM pattern.

Comment: An [MCR](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help. That being said, have you tried using a converter?
Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25001816/2596334) perhaps...

Comment: Basically the cell could be a ComboBox of values, or it could be just a simple TextBlock. When `Values` has values inside it (for example 1, 2, 3) 1 is preselected and when you double click on the cell a ComboBox appears with the other values and you can choose. On the other hand, `Values` may be null and I am setting only `SelectedValue`. I want when `Values` is null, when double clicking the cell, the ComboBox to not appear. Basically the cell to be readonly. And no, I have not tried using a converter as I don't know how to apply it in my case. I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: This is a like a list of requirements, which isn't the right way to ask a question. Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" If you do your best to follow the advice there, you'll get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to prevent the `DataGrid` from entering the edit mode when you double-click on the `TextBox` would be to handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event for the cell:

```
private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)sender;
    e.Handled = cell.DataContext is YourClass dataObject && !dataObject.Value.Any();
}
...
var templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn
{
    Header = e.PropertyName,
    CellTemplate = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValuesCellTemplate") as DataTemplate,
    CellEditingTemplate = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ValuesCellEditingTemplate") as DataTemplate,
    CellStyle = (sender as FrameworkElement).FindResource("ReadOnlyCellStyle") as Style,
};
```

**XAML**:

```
<Style x:Key="ReadOnlyCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseDown" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! As the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` is a `DataTable`, the `DataContext` of the cell is always `DataRowView`, therefore `dataObject` is null, do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Cast it to a `DataRowView` instead of a `YourClass`?

Comment: `e.Handled = cell.DataContext is DataRowView dataObject && ...`;

Comment: Tried this one, but how could I have access to `Values` (to check whether it is `null`) ?

Comment: Try `dataObject["Values"]`. Or please ask a new question about how to retrieve values from a `DataRowView`.

Comment: The proper way would be to handle the `DataGrid.BeginningEdit` event and cancel the edit mode by setting `DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs.Cancel` to `true`. Marking the mouse event as handled could lead to unexpected side effects.